# HOW can I draw ER diagram for mobile app?

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I build android app for education computer sciences , you can login or logout by Email or google account , this app consists 3 departments computer engineering , IT and Software, which department has 2 options undergraduate and graduate , when click on any option will display list of courses and when choose any course display list of lessons that list has 2 option videos or documents, so how can I draw ER diagram for database of app?

I tried draw ER diagram for database please check it . [ER diagram][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MMi0.png

Answer (score 0):

Add a type table, then combine all your course tables into one course table. Each row in that course table will then use a foreign key of an entry in the type table.

Comment: No, I have no ER tools. I think you should try.

Comment: You didn't do what I said, and now that you've changed the diagram in the question, nobody else can make sense of my answer.

Comment: what did you mean by type table?

Comment: You didn't combine all the course tables, and there's no type table.